# epspdfconversion isn't working

Tags: epstopdf

I'm with a problem with the package `epspdfconversion`. I use the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[help]{epspdfconversion}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage[pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=black]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
```

and when I try to add a figure:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ocupfd.eps}
\caption{a}
\end{figure}
```

the program gives me the following error:

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File `ocupfd-epspdf-to.pdf' not found
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you calling `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option? If you don't need any of the fancy options of **epspdfconversion**, maybe `\usepackage{epstopdf}` will do, without even the command line option, if your TeX distribution is recent.

Comment: @egreg How do I execute this `-shell-escape`option?

Comment: It depends on your settings: operating system and editor.

Comment: I use Ubuntu, and TeXMaker

Comment: @egreg Could you tell me how do I execute the `-shell-escape`option for the TeXMaker on Ubuntu?

Comment: When you open the "Commands" tab in the configuration window for Texmaker, in the box next to PdfLaTeX you have to add `-shell-escape` just before `%.tex` (separate it with spaces).

Comment: If you're using TeX Live 2010 or TeX Live 2011, you don't need to change anything but remove `\usepackage[help]{epspdfconversion}`. The `graphics.cfg` of TeX Live since 2010 contains code for on-the-fly conversion of eps to pdf with the default settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **epspdfconversion** package needs that `pdflatex` is called with the command line option `-shell-escape`. How this is done depends much on what is the TeX environment one uses.

For example, with Texmaker (or TeXStudio) it's sufficient to go to the configuration window and add the option in the PdfLaTeX tab so that it looks like

```bsh
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
```

Similarly for other TeX editors.

The package offers many fancy options. If one doesn't need them and has TeX Live 2010 or later (or MiKTeX 2.9), it's easier to load the package **epstopdf** and the conversion will be done automatically, without the need of the `-shell-escape` option.